# How do I output which files a process is calling upon?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, unix

In terminal how do I output which files a process is calling upon?  For instance, if I was using Adobe Premiere and I wanted show which project file Premiere had open via terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by `calling upon`.  If you are looking for all the files currently opened by your process, use `lsof`:

```
lsof -p PID
```

where `PID` is the ID of the process you are looking at.